# Vuejs pass arguments from body to function like pure JS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to pass in an argument to a function that I enter into my view in order to run code on said function.

Currently I have a 5 functions that all basically do the same thing, and I'm trying to refactor them into 1 that takes the values I pass and performs some logic. It might be easier to explain what I'm trying to do with code.

This is my current code in my view:

```
<v-card-text :class="darkBodyPurpleCardClassFix">Manage</v-card-text>
<v-card-text :class="lightBodyPurpleCardClassFix">Fees</v-card-text>
```

And then here are those two functions bound to `class` both under `computed`:

```
lightBodyPurpleCardClassFix(){
  switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
    case 'xs': return '450px';
    case 'sm': return this.mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList;
    case 'md': return this.mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList;
    case 'lg': return this.largeLightPurpleBodyCLassList;
    case 'xl': return this.largeLightPurpleBodyCLassList;
  }
},
darkBodyPurpleCardClassFix(){
  switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
    case 'xs': return '450px';
    case 'sm': return this.mediumDarkPurpleBodyClassList;
    case 'md': return this.mediumDarkPurpleBodyClassList;
    case 'lg': return this.largeDarkPurpleClassList;
    case 'xl': return this.largeDarkPurpleClassList;
  }
},
```

What I'd love to do is to just pass in some arguments, and use those arguments in the function. Something along these lines

```
<v-card-text :class="classFix(purple, light)">Manage</v-card-text>
```

And then use those in a `function` something like this:

```
classFix(color, value ){
 doSomethingWithColor(color);
 this.data = value;
};
```

That `color` and `value` are arguments that I would enter into my own code so I could adjust the class list all with 1 function instead of the handful I have now.

EDIT:
This is what some of the `data` elements look like:

```
mediumPurpleCreateClassList: ['body-2', 'pb-3', 'pt-2', 'px-2', 'my_dark_purple_section'],
largePurpleCreateClassList: ['subheading', 'pb-3', 'pt-2', 'px-2', 'my_dark_purple_section'],
```

And what I'd like to do is just pass into a function `medium` & `purple` & `create` and then run my logic off of those arguments.

Comment: Can you show what `this.mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList` and `this.largeDarkPurpleClassList` or others are?

Comment: There we go, updated the question!

Comment: Is this it `classFix(darkOrLight, color){
  switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
    case 'xs': return '450px';
    case 'sm': return this['medium' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
    case 'md': return this['medium' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
    case 'lg': return this['large' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
    case 'xl': return this['large' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
  }
}` ? Example usage: `classFix('dark', 'purple')`

Comment: Yes that's the idea, but where can I put `classFix(darkOrLight, Color)` ?

Comment: Like: `<v-card-text :class="classFix('dark', 'purple')">Manage</v-card-text>
<v-card-text :class="classFix('light', 'purple')">Fees</v-card-text>`

Comment: Yea shoot @acdcjunior that doesn't work.. I'm getting errors about `classFix` not being a function.. TypeError: _vm.classFix is not a function

Comment: You have to declare it in the methods.

Comment: yes! It worked.. thank you!

Comment: Okay, can I add an answer to summarize?

Comment: definitely! I'll accept once I can.

Comment: There you go. Let me know if it's not clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method like:

```js
methods: {
    // ...
    classFix(darkOrLight, color) {
        switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
            case 'xs': return '450px';
            case 'sm': return this['medium' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
            case 'md': return this['medium' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
            case 'lg': return this['large' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
            case 'xl': return this['large' + darkOrLight + color + 'ClassList'];
        }
    }
}
```

And use (bind) it in the template as follows:

```html
<v-card-text :class="classFix('dark', 'purple')">Manage</v-card-text>
<v-card-text :class="classFix('light', 'purple')">Fees< /v-card-text>
```

### Reasoning:

This alternative takes advantage of [JavaScript's **property accessor** syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Basically, any property present like:

```
this.mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList
```

Can be acessed through:

```
this['mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList']
```

Notice that what is between `[` and `]` are strings. And being strings, you can use any variable:

```
var myField = 'mediumLightPurpleBodyCLassList';
this[myField];
```

And create/manipulate that variable in anyway you would with any regular string variable:

```
var myColor = 'LightPurple';
var myField = 'medium' + color + 'BodyCLassList';
this[myField];
```

And, in the above suggested `classFix` method, those variables are the functions arguments (which, in the end of the day, are local variables).